# How can I eliminate the delay when switching view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am switching between two view controllers but there is a 1 or 2 second delay before the second view is functioning. How can I implement this more efficiently so everything is loaded when the app is started?

Here's my code:

I have a button making the switch:

```
- (IBAction)soundListButton:(id)sender {
    BBRViewController * controller = [[BBRViewController alloc]
                                      initWithNibName:@"BBRViewController" bundle:nil];

    controller.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My viewDidLoad on the second view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"applause_y" ofType:@"wav"]];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, 
                                     &SoundID);

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"applause_y", @"applause_y", nil];
    self.listData = array;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to move the sound to the viewDidAppear ?

Comment: I did, but the problem persists. It seems to be the array creation that slows it down.